# How to identify sessions in traffic logs by detecting periods of idleness or inactivity?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, haproxy

I'm looking at traffic logs (collected through HAProxy) and trying to identify user sessions (aka visits). I'm defining a user as a unique IP + User Agent checksum, or else where available, a user ID for logged-in users.

I'm not exactly an SQL wiz, and I'm wondering if there's some way to identify a new session as defined as any logged event after 30 minutes since the last logged event by that same user. We use T-SQL, and we're running on SQL Server 2012.

It may be that I'm overlooking something obvious that confounds this session ID methodology. I'd appreciate any wisdom that comes to mind.

The db schema looks something like this, filtered for just the user defined by the UA: `abcdefghij` + IP: `11.11.11.1`:

```
Id   || User Agent ||     IP     || AccountID ||   RouteName   ||   CreationDate
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9    || abcdefghij || 11.11.11.1 ||   NULL    ||     Home      || 2015-05-29 00:00:25
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
45   || abcdefghij || 11.11.11.1 ||   NULL    ||   Home/Photo  || 2015-05-29 00:00:26
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
55   || abcdefghij || 11.11.11.1 ||   NULL    ||   Home/Photo  || 2015-05-29 00:00:27
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125 || abcdefghij || 11.11.11.1 ||   NULL    ||     Home      || 2015-05-29 01:02:03
```

For simplicity's sake let's say we'll restart all sessions every time a new day (new table) starts. So we're looking at 2 sessions above - all sessions by the user during the day.

In reality we're talking about hundreds of thousands of UA + IP combinations. I'm hoping to be able to return a list of users, plus count of sessions for a given day.

Answer (score 3):

You can caluclate the difference between subsequent rows by creating a CTE with row numbers created by row_number(), then self joining with an offset. Your complete query would look something like this:

```
with events as
(
select "User Agent", 
       ip as user,
       creationdate, 
       row_number() over (partition by "User Agent", ip order by creationdate) rn
       from SourceTable
)
select "User Agent", ip, count(*)
from 
events e1
join events e2 on e1.rn = e2.rn-1
where datediff(minute, e2.creationdate, e1.creationdate) >=30
group by "User Agent", ip
```

Comment: Excellent answer - very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728602/sql-datediff-find-datediff-between-rows/5728715#5728715

Comment: I'm getting an ambiguous column name error for 'User Agent', and two invalid column name errors for 'ip', but I think this is real close.