# Dynamically Calculate DateDiff for all rows in Date column MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate the difference in days between dates for consecutive rows in a single column called `Date_col`.  I then want to put those differences into a new column called Expected_Results.

I have the following code so far:

```
DECLARE @datedifferences DATETIME

SET @datedifferences = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(Date_col), MAX(Date_col)) FROM Schema.Table)

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 Date_col
FROM Database.Schema.Table
WHERE Date_col = @datedifferences
ORDER BY Date_col
```

The below is what I'd like to have returned:

```
Date_col    Expected_Results
1/1/2018    --
2/2/2018    31
3/3/2018    31
4/4/2018    31
5/5/2018    31
6/6/2018    31
7/7/2018    31
8/8/2018    31
```

However, the query runs successfully but nothing is returned.  I suspect this is because I'm missing some kind of loop to iterate over the rows.  How can I incorporate a while loop into query to successfully iterate over the rows such that the query prints the expected results?

Comment: @datedifferences` is declared as `DATETIME`, but is assigned to the return value of the `DATEDIFF` function, which [returns an integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: can you post the actual error

Comment: [`Lag`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the (modern) way to access data from a prior row within a `select`. That's assuming you have an undisclosed table with a column containing dates and want to display the dates in order along with the number of days between dates in consecutive rows. Your question lacks a question, among other details. Not sure what the "day sum differences" are about. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728602/sql-datediff-find-datediff-between-rows

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking that this is all one statement?   Because it's not.  You have 3 separate statements:

```
DECLARE @datedifferences datetime;

SET @datedifferences = DATEDIFF(day, min(Date_col), max(Date_col));

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 Date_col
FROM Database.Schema.Table
WHERE Date_col = @datedifferences
ORDER BY Date_col;
```

The middle statement (`SET...`) has no access to the FROM clause of the SELECT statement below it, so it has no knowledge of the `Date_col` you are referencing in it.   Therefore `Date_col` **is** an invalid column name in the middle statement.

Comment: . . . You need `@datedifferences` as `INT` type instead of `datetime`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma that's also true, but it's not the reason for the error message in the question.

Comment: @TabAlleman The OP finally say what he want to do exactly in a comment under my answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman, I have added the FROM clause to the SET statement, and while now the query runs, it does not return any values.  Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

That because the `SET` part, where hte `Date_Col` column is not known/accessible, you need to specify from where like

```
DECLARE @datedifferences datetime;
SET @datedifferences = (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, min(Date_col), max(Date_col)) FROM Database.Schema.Table);
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 Date_col
FROM Database.Schema.Table
WHERE Date_col = @datedifferences
ORDER BY Date_col;
```

Now, the **[`DATEDIFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function return `INT` datatype, and your `@datedifferences` declared as `DATETIME` datatype.
This for the first, so you can't use it to compare in the `WHERE` clause cause I don't think you want to compare `DATETIME` with `INT`, which mean even you change the datatype of your variable to `INT` this part of your query won't work

```
WHERE Date_col = @datedifferences
```

---

Now, according to your code I think you want to select the top 100 where `Date_Col` between the `MAX()` and `MIN()` dates from your table, so your code maybe looks like

```
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(Date_Col) FROM Database.Schema.Table);
DECLARE @MinDate DATEIME = (SELECT MIN(Date_Col) FROM Database.Schema.Table);

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 Date_col
FROM Database.Schema.Table
WHERE Date_col BETWEEN @MaxDate AND @MinDate
ORDER BY Date_col;
```

Update:

> I just want to calculate the date_diffs for the first 100 rows in the date_col

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Day, MIN(Date_Col), MAX(Date_Col)) As Def
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 100 Date_Col
    FROM Database.Schema.Table
    ORDER BY Date_Col
) T;
```

Comment: . . .  You need `@datedifferences` as `INT` type instead of `datetime`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Yeah, my answer still has other updates, ty BTW

Comment: when I substitute datetime for int I get this error: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: and how do I then insert the result of the @datedifferences into a new column?

Comment: The query runs successfully but doesn't return anything

Comment: @YogeshSharma Finally, the OP says what he want to do really :)

Comment: You misunderstood what I said.  This answer is not what I'm trying to do.  I'm not looking to calculate one date_diff, I want to calculate the date_diffs for all the rows dynamically.

Comment: @thedatasleuth Well, a DDL, Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: @Sami, can you please remove your downvote so my question can have more visibility and can be answered?